# Run Powershell script files step by step in WPF (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, powershell, asynchronous

I am a novice in C# and have a GUI in WPF where at some point it should automatically start executing Powershell scripts, but preferably one by one. As I see all methods run at once without waiting previous to finish, so my question is: what is better to use some kind of threads or async methods?

If I try to use task.WaitForExit(); then it freezes GUI, which is not acceptable. I have tried to use timer as well, but it looks like it doesn't see this it at all. Besides I have more ps1 files and several bat files, which need to be run one by one.
Could you tell please which method is better to use and how to combine it with active GUI in this case?

```
public partial class Start_deployment : Window
{
    public Start_deployment()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Run_scripts();
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }

    public void Run_scripts()
    {
        var ps1File = @"C:\test\Install.ps1";
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "powershell.exe",
            Arguments = $"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -file \"{ps1File}\"",
            UseShellExecute = false
        };
        var task = Process.Start(startInfo);
        //task.WaitForExit();
    }

    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the Power Shell gui instead?

Comment: What if you run the `RunScripts` method on non-gui thread via `Task.Run()`? Is that ok for you?

Comment: @MarkKram As far as I understood PS is missing threads support...

Comment: Well it does kind of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325911/how-does-threading-in-powershell-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Process.Start()` returns `Process` instance, which has Exited event. Subscribe to that event to receive notification when it finished:

```
public partial class Start_deployment : Window
{
    public Start_deployment()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Run_scripts();
    }

    public void Run_scripts()
    {
        var ps1File = @"C:\test\Install.ps1";
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "powershell.exe",
            Arguments = $"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -file \"{ps1File}\"",
            UseShellExecute = false
        };
        var proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
        proc.Exited += OnProcessExited;
    }

    private void OnProcessExited(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {            
        // todo, e.g.
        // System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks great! The only thing is that it doesn't reach the OnProcessExited method...

Comment: @Oleg_D, does process quit or it keeps working in background? can you confirm via TaskManager or ProcessExplorer?

Comment: Yes, there is still a process and Stop button in PowerShell ISE still active.

Comment: `Exited` event will happen when process is finished. I suppose it is possible to call smth like "quit" in powershell?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who wants the OnProcessExited to work, you'll need to 'proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;'. I found it somewhere. Below is my code.

```
    private void Run_scripts_2()
    {
        var ps1File = scriptPath;
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "powershell.exe",
            Arguments = $"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -file \"{ps1File}\" \"{HostName}\" \"{DatabaseName}\" \"{GetFileNamePath()}\"",
            UseShellExecute = false
        };
        var proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        proc.Exited += new EventHandler(OnProcessExited);
    }

    private void OnProcessExited(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        ToggleGrandGrid(true);

        if (dispatcherTimer != null && dispatcherTimer.IsEnabled) 
        { 
            dispatcherTimer.Stop(); 
        }

        if(stopWatch != null && stopWatch.IsRunning) 
        {
            stopWatch.Stop();
        }

        UpdateBackupScript($"OnProcessExited(..) - StopWatch.Elapsed = [{stopWatch.Elapsed}]");

        theLog?.logger.LogDebug("PS Script Done");
    }
```